# Can I run commands from a file uploaded to my Cisco ASA 5500?

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa

I have to run a lot of ACL/access-group and network-object commands, and I have found a 1024 character limit for each command - even if it spans multiple lines. In code, I use 1,000 chars as the limit, and send as many lines to CLI as will fit, via SSH, at a time. This takes a LONG time.

I'm thinking like a shell script in *nix, or a batch file in Windows.

I have seen many articles talking about import/export configurations, but I am talking about running commands on a running system, not taking it down for reboot/restart. I am not changing the core image, just some access parameters that can be changed on the fly on the ASA without the need for reboot or shut/no shut.

Desired: A way to run the contents of a tftp'd/ftp'd/scp'd file sent to the ASA as if I entered it on the CLI. I would prepare the commands, write the file, send the file, then run the contents of the file line-by-line, as if I were logged into the ASA.

Comment: The first thing that this question makes me think is that you're doing something wrong, honestly.  You have so many commands that are so long that it takes a long time to **send** them over a command line interface?  And, evidently, you do this often enough that you want to embed these commands on your ASAs?  (It also really sounds like you should be exporting and importing a lot of these settings in config files, but whatever... something is definitely not being done right here.)

Comment: fwiw the one time I wanted to do this, I copied the `running-config` to the flash, SCP'd it to my local machine, edited it locally, pushed it back to the flash, replaced the `startup-config` file with it, crossed my fingers and did a reload.

Comment: @HopelessN00b, I understand your comment/position. I can ask a different question if you like. An example: Let's say you have to block an entire country, or even continent, and there are hundreds of network-objects. How would you add or remove them before you grow old? :) SSH is the only assumed protocol. Thx!

Comment: @HopelessN00b, I read your comment. You say that the commends will be run often. I didn't mean that. What I tried to say is that there might be large changes to the config (al/ag/ng/no) that are not permanent. I didn't mean to say the same command would be run frequently. Sorry for the confusion! :(

Comment: @YumiKoizumi I probably wouldn't use that approach to block a country/continent.

Comment: @ewwhite, I appreciate that you disagree about it being a good idea, but what would help more than that is to hear how you WOULD do it.

Comment: @YumiKoizumi I wouldn't necessarily endeavor to block an entire continent/country. What's the deeper issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On ASA (and IOS), this can be done by copying the commands to running-config:

```
asa# copy tftp running-config
```

This has the effect of merging the commands in a file on your TFTP server with the running configuration, just as if you typed or pasted them in by hand. The file should contain the verbatim commands you want to run. Of course, you can copy from any source supported by the ASA, such as FTP or HTTP(S). I don't know if the built-in SCP server supports this, though.

The only catch is that it only works in config mode. For instance, you can't use it to run a bunch of "show" commands. You'd probably need to use Expect for that (or possibly EEM, a Jason noted).

Comment: If it doesn't involve a reboot, I'm interested. Where can I read up on it? (I mean a specific page/site where they cover the aspects of adding/replacing lines in the running-config without reboot)

Comment: It's noted as the first bullet point under Usage Guidelines for the copy command in the [ASA command reference](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/asa-command-reference/A-H/cmdref1/c4.html#pgfId-2171368). A reboot is not required, and the changes take effect immediately.

Comment: James Sneeringer, I read that and was blown away! Thank you!!!

Comment: I have thoroughly tested, and here is the bottom line: It runs the copied file as if you were in config term, but you call it from 'plain' enable. It executes the file top down, line for line AND you need to have a CR/LF for the last line, or it is ignored.

Comment: @YumiKoizumi - Nicely done. The only thing I'd add (because I brought it up) is that, if you're doing this on IOS, the last command should always be `end`, just as you'd see at the end of `startup-config`. This does not apply to ASA, though.

Comment: Oh, and if it comes across a line it can't implement (some of mine had bad network/subnet combos for network-objects, it carps about it and keeps chugging: 
 (please pardon SO not respecting formatting) 
Accessing ftp://userName:passWord@1.2.3.4/Upd.txt...!!!!!
[...]
Removing object-group (someOG) failed; it does not exist
.network: IP address/mask <196.3.67.0/255.255.248.0> doesn't pair
...network: IP address/mask <193.254.1.0/255.255.252.0> doesn't pair
[...]

It worked _really_ well! :)

Answer (score 1):

As of ASA code 9.2, EEM (Embedded Event Manager) support is added.  This *may* give you a way to read commands from a file and apply them.

I'm far from an expert on EEM, but the folks who could help you figure this out are @ https://supportforums.cisco.com/community/5941/eem-scripting

Let us know what you find out!

Comment: I asked here: https://supportforums.cisco.com/discussion/12269716/can-i-use-eem-upload-long-scripts-and-run-them

Comment: EEM seems to be just like RDBMS triggers & actions. If X, then do Y kind of stuff. I just have a TON of commands to execute a few times/day to adjust ACLs, and doing them in 1k chunks was insanely time consuming (even in automation!). I went from 4 hours to 150 seconds!